# NodeJS Software Driven Temporary Wall Outlet Battery Buffer For Server

Tags: web-server, node.js, usb, server

I have have a Node server running in my basement with a backup generator, kicking on after ~15 seconds (long enough for the server to go down), in a place where power outages are routine. SO, are there any battery-buffers that I can hook up inbetween my server and the wall outlet that will:

- Provide a USB connection to my server to signal when it's on emergency battery power.
- Provide NodeJS plugin software to add in event listeners for when the server temporarily switches to the emergency buffer power.
- Provide ~1200 watts for ~3 seconds.
- Provide ~100 watts for ~20 seconds after that.
- Provide uninterrupted power when power outage.
- Preferably, but not required, the ability to provide this emergency power in the event of a power surge without the device being blown out. In addition, resuming normal power after power surge done.

Comment: Sorry - this is really a hardware recommendation request with a tiny software feature. Most UPSs (Uninterruptible Power Supplies) will do pretty much what you need and most of them have a USB connection that lets you know when you are under emergency power. Voting to close but if you reword this as NodeJS software to query generic or specific UPS via USB will vote to reopen. Don't make the classic mistake of putting the server on UPS but not the router.

Comment: APC Smart-UPS should be able to accomplish at least most of what you desire.